# The necessity of LU decomposition (using numpy as an example)

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, linear-algebra

I am trying to understand the necessity of LU decomposition using numpy and scipy libraries. From what I understand is that we want to solve Ax = b, we first factorize A into two triangular matrices L and U then solve LUx = b by solving Ly = b then Ux = y. By solving triangular matrices, we can reduce time compare to Gaussian Elimination.

So, I tired this idea in python using numpy and scipy.

I first construct A and b using toy examples:

```
A = np.array([[2, 1, 0, 5], [1, 2, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 6, 4.5]])
b = np.array([9, 10, -2, 3])
```

Then first solve this toy example in np.solve

```
%timeit np.linalg.solve(A, b )
```

The time is

> 9.76 µs ± 782 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Then I use factorization to solve this system:

```
lu, piv = linalg.lu_factor(A)
%timeit linalg.lu_solve((lu, piv), b)
```

I saw the output is

> 18.8 µs ± 213 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

, which is quiet slow compared to np.solve.

So, my question is, why np.solve is faster than linalg.lu_factor? My guess is that numpy.solve does not use Gaussian Elimination to solve the equations? A little confused with the result here.

## Edit

Now, I use a much larger matrix to do the experiment (10000 x 10000).

Here is the result:
for np.linalg.solve

```
8.64 s ± 180 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each);
```

for scipy.linalg.lu_solve

```
121 ms ± 3.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each).
```

For lu_solve, I only count the time on solving, the decomposition part is not counted. It is now much faster!

Comment: I'd like to know source of the claim that "_By solving triangular matrices, we can reduce time compare to Gaussian Elimination._". AFAIU LU decomposition is basically a modified form of Gaussian elimination so time complexity of LU decomposition itself can't be better than for Gaussian elimination. LU decomposition might be beneficial if you want to solve many `Ax = b` with different `b`s but for single system I see no reasons why it should be any faster.

Comment: Try it on much, *much* bigger matrices, to make sure that the overhead of Python talking to C-algorithms is (relatively) as small as possible. Comparing it on 4x4 matrix is kind of pointless, allocating all the frame stacks for function calls will take longer than the actual calculations.

Comment: @SergGr Maybe my previous question is confusing. I am saying that after LU decomposition, using L and U to solve the equations should be faster than Gaussian elimination then do the solving.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I now use a much larger matrix to do this, and the result is much faster for lu_solve.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a partial answer, since I dispute one of your premises.

You write that "LU solve should be faster than Gaussian Elimination." You seem to misunderstand the purpose of LU decomposition. If you are solving just one such problem (`Ax=b` where matrix `A` and vector `b` are given), LU decomp is no faster than Gaussian elimination. Indeed, the decomposition's algorithm is very similar to the elimination and is no faster.

The advantage of LU decomposition comes when you are given matrix `A` and you want to solve the equation `Ax=b` for *multiple* different given vectors `b`. Gaussian elimination needs to start over from scratch, and each solution will take the same amount of time. In LU decomposition you can store the resulting matrices `L` and `U` from the first calculation, and that greatly speeds up the solutions to the succeeding equations that use different vectors `b`.

You can read more about this at the section in Numerical Recipes in C about  [LU Decomposition and Its Applications](http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/linearalgebra/NumericalRecipiesInC/c2-3.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the docstring for [`numpy.linalg.solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html).  It says in the "Notes" section "The solutions are computed using LAPACK routine _gesv".  (The underscore is a place-holder for a character that corresponds to a data type.  For example, `dgesv` uses double precision.)

The [documentation for `dgesv`](http://www.math.utah.edu/software/lapack/lapack-d/dgesv.html) explains that it uses the LU decomposition.  So you are more-or-less replicating the calculation, but you are doing more steps in Python, so your code is slower.